# How to persist state in all slices of reducer, using redux persist?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, redux-persist, react-state-management

I have added, redux persist to my app. I have a root reducer which contains different reducers like "Auth", "Orders", "Products", "Transactions" etc.

problem is my Orders and Products reducer is persisted properly but Auth and Transactions reducer does not persist.

I tried debugging, I have can see no data in Auth and Transactions slice of root reducer

**This is my top level config**

```
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  // blacklist: ['navigation']   pass state which you want to ignore
  blacklist: ['navigation', 'Error', 'Address', 'form'],
  stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2,
};
```

```
const pReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
```

**exporting like**

```
export const configureStore = createStore(pReducer, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
export const persistor = persistStore(configureStore);
```

**In My App.js**

```
  <Provider store={store}>
      {/* the loading and persistor props are both required! */}
        <PersistGate loading={<Spinner />} persistor={persistor}>
           <CommuneVendorRoot />
       </PersistGate>
   </Provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { persistCombineReducers } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/es/storage'
import todos from '../reducers/reducers';
import autoMergeLevel2 from 'redux-persist/lib/stateReconciler/autoMergeLevel2';

console.log(todos)
const config = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: storage,
  debug: true,
  stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2
};


const rootReducer = persistCombineReducers(config, {
  Transactions: todos
});
export default rootReducer;
```

> Please check above code it working fine. and let me know if you
>   still have any issue

Comment: Actually, I found the issue. In Reducer when returning default state, I was returning it as 
return {...state}
 instead of 
return state;